# Is filling the internal storage of an Android device using `dd` sufficient for data removal?

Tags: android, deletion, data-remanence

I have a rooted phone I'm willing to sell, but I had Personally Identifiable Information (PII) on it and I am questioning whether filling the internal storage with null bytes using `dd` would be sufficient to prevent data recovery by possible third parties.

I'm not fully familiar with the inner workings of the Android system and the differences it shares with the core Linux.

Comment: If you have encryption on a factory reset should be sufficient for removing all data securely.

Comment: What is the threat and what is the risk? If you are a casual user and sell the phone to another casual user, a factory reset is enough. If your phone really contains life critical secrets and you want to be protected against governmental agencies level forensics, just do not sell it but physically destroy it.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I had a photo of my personal ID on there. I've used the traditional `rm -rf` afterwards via ADB Shell. The question is what's the probability of that information being still available if somebody tried to recover "hidden" data?

Comment: @EsaJokinen I am running Android 12; I've read that Android 10 and upwards enforces this rule by default?

Comment: `rm -rf` never destroys the data itself but just removes the links to it from the file system. That means that it is still possible to identify removed files by searching well known patterns on the disk device. `dd` is of course more secure because it overwrites the data but: 1/ if you overwrite system data, you phone will not be useable any longer 2/ unless you know the specifics of the implementation of your phone you cannot be sure that there are no *hidden partitions*. BTW and IMHO, an ID card is personal data but not secret data

Comment: Would filling the internal storage to the max using `dd` to write null bytes to a file a couple of times prevent recovery? Something like [DoD 5220.22-M](https://exwc.navfac.navy.mil/Portals/88/Documents/EXWC/DoD_Locks/PDFs/DODI-5220-22-C2.pdf) but not this extreme as I'm pretty sure it will significantly decrease the lifespan of NAND flash.